# How to handle OAuth2AuthenticationException: Client authentication failed: client_id in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server, spring-boot-security

I'm implementing new Spring Authorization server (*spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server version 1.0.0*). I have created following two classes to handle exceptions:

```
public class RestExceptionTranslationFilter implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
   @Override
   public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
      // Code to handle the exception
   }
}

public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
   public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {
      // Code to handle the exception
   }
}
```

I have registered both of them like this:

```
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
...
OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();  
authorizationServerConfigurer.tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint ->
             ((OAuth2TokenEndpointConfigurer)tokenEndpoint).errorResponseHandler(new RestExceptionTranslationFilter())
);
...
http.exceptionHandling(exceptions ->
            exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint()));
}
```

Now I'm able to handle the `OAuth2AuthenticationException` exceptions and other exceptions and to return the response that my implementation requires. For example, this exception is handled correctly:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: OAuth 2.0 Parameter: grant_type
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter.throwError(OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter.java:260) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter.java:159) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
```

But, what's confusing me, and I cant solve it, why the same `OAuth2AuthenticationException` exception is not handled by this configuration in case when its thrown like this from `ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider`:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: Client authentication failed: client_id
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider.throwInvalidClient(ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider.java:151) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
```

Is it possible to handle this exception and how as I would really like not to disclose the message  `"error": "invalid_client"` to the possible attackers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Configuring Client Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-model.html#configuring-client-authentication) in the reference. It would be very similar to how you configured the `tokenEndpoint()`:

```java
    authorizationServerConfigurer
        .clientAuthentication(clientAuthentication ->
            clientAuthentication
                .errorResponseHandler(new RestExceptionTranslationFilter()) 
        );
```

**Note:** "TranslationFilter" is probably not the best name for an `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, but is a minor detail.